# How to display images in groups column in vis.js?

Tags: image, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

How to display images in the "groups" column in vis.js, like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have a similar issue : i've just put the `<img>` tag in my content :

```
"content": "some text <br> <img src='myImg.jpg' style='width: 48px; height: 48px;'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to personalize the "groups" column, you can use the property `groupTemplate` in the timeline option (http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options).

You can see a more complex example in the official examples:
http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/groups/groupsEditable.html